# Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3},\zeta):\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to determine the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3},\zeta):\mathbb{Q}$, where $\zeta=e^{2\pi i/5}$. I have the following information:

- $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3},\zeta)$ is the splitting field for $x^5-3$, whose roots are $\sqrt[5]{3}, \zeta \sqrt[5]{3}, \zeta^2 \sqrt[5]{3}, \zeta^3 \sqrt[5]{3},$ and $\zeta^4 \sqrt[5]{3}$.
- $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3},\zeta):\mathbb{Q}$ has degree 20.
- If $\sigma$ is an element of the Galois group, then $\sigma$ must send a root of $x^5-3$ to a root of $x^5-3$. So the Galois group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_5$ with order 20.
- $\sigma$ is completely determined by where it sends $\sqrt[5]{3}$ and $\zeta$ (the basis elements for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{3},\zeta):\mathbb{Q}$).

There is a unique subgroup of $S_5$ of order 20, which is $\langle (1\,2\,3\,4\,5),(1\,2\,4\,3)\rangle$, but without using this, how can I determine the Galois group structure?

Also, how can I show it's not abelian?

Comment: To show it is not abelian, note that you have one automorphism given by complex conjugation (fixes $\sqrt[5]{3}$, and exchanges $\zeta\sqrt[5]{3}$ with $\zeta^4\sqrt[5]{3}$ and $\zeta^2\sqrt[5]{3}$ with $\zeta^3\sqrt[5]{3}$), and one that fixes $\zeta$ and sends $\sqrt[5]{3}$ to $\zeta\sqrt[5]{3}$. Check what happens when you compose them in the two different orders.

Comment: To realize it as a subgroup of $S_5$ explicitly, think about what it does to the roots of $x^5-3$; verify that you can just decide where to map $\sqrt[5]{3}$ and $\zeta\sqrt[5]{3}$ (as long as they are not mapped to the same thing), and then number the five roots and see what happens to them under the maps.

Comment: Did you mean $\zeta^4$ where you wrote $\zeta^5$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes; it's fixed

Comment: @ArturoMagidin For your second comment, deciding where $\sqrt[5]{3}$ and $\zeta \sqrt[5]{3}$ are sent to determines where the basis elements $\sqrt[5]{3}$ and $\zeta$ are sent to, which then completely determines the automorphism, correct? And there are $5\cdot 4=20$ possible choices for mapping those two elements.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin To see the group structure, do I need to explicitly write out each of the 20 elements and figure out the subgroups?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Or I guess now I've found 2 elements, one corresponding to $(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)$ and another corresponding to $(2\,3\,5\,4)$. Sorry I'm rusty on group theory - how does this determine the whole group structure; or how do I get all the subgroups from this?

Comment: What I’m saying is that instead of thinking about $\sqrt[5]{3}$ and $\zeta$ separately, you can think about what is happening to the roots of $x^5-3$. Which has the added benefit of having some *geometry* to it, since they happen to be the vertices of a nice regular pentagon on the complex plane...And you can try to figure out what happens to that pentagon as a result of the automorphisms....

Answer (score 2):

This is the Galois group of $x^5-3$. 
In general, the Galois group of $x^n-a$ is explicitly known, see here:

[Computing the Galois group of polynomials $x^n-a \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204552/computing-the-galois-group-of-polynomials-xn-a-in-mathbbqx)

**Proposition [Jacobson, Velez]:** One has $G\cong \mathbb{Z}/n \rtimes (\mathbb{Z}/n)^{\times}$ if and only if $n$ is odd, or $n$ is even *and* $\sqrt{a}\not\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$.

Here $n=5$ is odd, so we know that $G\cong \Bbb Z/5\rtimes \Bbb Z/4$ is a solvable, non-abelian group of order $20$.